# Null pointer error when reading a property file from another package

Tags: java, selenium, properties, webdriver, testng

My project folder structure is as below (Selenium +testng)

Proj
--**Data folder**
---General.properties
--**src folder**
---libraby package
----library.java
--testcases package
---testcase1 (testng test, extending library)

Problem: Null pointer when reading general properties file in library.java, but same code works fine when placed inside @test method in testcase. Whys is this happening? i want to read the properties inside library only, what should i do? please help.

```
public class Library{
public static Properties Prop = null;
public static FileInputStream sFileIn = null;
public static final String sProjpath = System.getProperty("user.dir").toString(); 
public void Initialization () throws Throwable
{
    sFileIn = new FileInputStream(sProjpath+"\\Data\\General.properties");
Prop.load(sFileIn);}
```

Comment: Your username is misspelled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The null pointer exception is because the `public static Properties Prop = null;` makes it null

To overcome this `public static Properties Prop = new Properties();` is to be used

May be your are initializing the `Prop` object somewhere in your test case, so it works fine

Comment: Thanks Harshavardhan, and ya that makes sense, i have never initialized the object anywhere just a null and am directly trying to load it.